# Using DOMFormHasPassword and DOMInputPasswordAdded events in chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener, google-contacts-api

**tl;dr:**
I'm trying to figure out how to use the **DOMFormHasPassword** and **DOMInputPasswordAdded** events in chrome extensions.

I'm trying to develop a password manager extension in chrome for my 
school project. To make it, I would need a way to identify a login form and fill it automatically. So far I had relative success, but I encountered a problem: I would scan the page for a login form **on page load**, so if any form were to be added through javascript my extension would miss it.

I have googled the matter and found the terms **DOMFormHasPassword** and **DOMInputPasswordAdded** in some locations online, such as [this one](https://dolske.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/a-change-in-password-manager/) that states that the DOMFormHasPassword event was added to chrome, and [some sort of an example](https://github.com/GaloisInc/hacrypto/blob/master/src/Javascript/Mozilla/old_snapshots/passwordmgr/test/test_basic_form_pwevent.html) of its use that I couldn't understand.

I've tried adding the events with `document.addEventListener`, without any success.

I also encountered the term **SpecialPowers** that I don't understand, and I think understanding it might solve my problem.

I Would be very grateful if you could even direct me to a documentation of those events, because I can't seem to to find it. Thank you for your time!

Comment: DOMContentLoaded can't handle it?

Comment: @danielarend seems like it can't, I tried to include it in my code and it wouldn't recognize forms like the one at the [Microsoft login](https://login.live.com/)